# how to use Zend Route Regex to route a url to another one?

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-route

i have a url like this: `view_test.php?user=56`

and i am trying to get it here:

```
    $router->addRoute(
        'test',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'test/view/:id',
            array(
                'module' => 'test',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'view'
            )
        )
    );
```

basically from `view_test.php?user=56` to `/test/view/56`

im not sure how to handle the `?`.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK,  in a route, you can't reference the url's query-string content, just its request path. But you could do the following:

Add a route that maps the old url to a redirect action:

```
$router->addRoute('view-test-redirect', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
    'view_test.php',
    array(
        'module' => 'test',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'view-test-redirect',
    )
);
```

Also, add a route representing your "real" action:

```
$router->addRoute('view-test', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'view/test/:user',
    array(
        'module' => 'test',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'view-test',
    )
);
```

The action name `view-test-redirect` corresponds to the action below:

```
public function viewTestRedirectAction()
{
    $user = (int) $this->_getParam('user', null);
    if (!$user){
        throw new \Exception('Missing user');
    }
    $this->_helper->redirector->goToRouteAndExit(array('user' => $user), 'view-test');
}
```

Then your `view-test` action can do things in the expected way:

```
public function viewTestController()
{
    $user = (int) $this->_getParam('user', null);
    if (!$user){
        throw new \Exception('Missing user');
    }
    // Read db, assign results to view, praise unicorns, etc.
}
```

Not tested, just brain-dumping to demonstrate the idea.